# How to get the document quality score in google document AI as the "Intelligent document quality processor" is not available now?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

How to get the document quality score in google document AI as the "Intelligent document quality processor" is not available now?

Used general-ocr and tried to get the entities(as the documentation shows entities has the quality score), but no entities found.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the information about getting Document Quality information from the Document OCR Processor.

Note - For the Document OCR processor, you must use processor version `pretrained-ocr-v1.1-2022-09-12` to get the quality information.

[Document OCR Processor - Handling the Processing Response](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#basic_text:%7E:text=to%20the%20first.-,Starting%20with%20processor%20version%20pretrained%2Docr%2Dv1.1%2D2022%2D09%2D12,-%2C%20the%20Document%20OCR)

> Starting with [processor
> version](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/manage-processor-versions)
> `pretrained-ocr-v1.1-2022-09-12`, the [Document
> OCR](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_doc-ocr)
> processor   can also perform quality assessment of a document based on
> its readability.   This quality assessment is a quality score in `[0, 1]`, where `1` means perfect quality.   The quality score is returned
> in the
> [`Page.imageQualityScores`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#Page.FIELDS.image_quality_scores)
> field.   All detected defects are listed as `quality/defect_*` and
> sorted in descending order by confidence value.

```json
{
  "pages": [
    {
      "imageQualityScores": {
        "qualityScore": 0.7811847,
        "detectedDefects": [
          {
            "type": "quality/defect_document_cutoff",
            "confidence": 1.0
          },
          {
            "type": "quality/defect_glare",
            "confidence": 0.97849524
          },
          {
            "type": "quality/defect_text_cutoff",
            "confidence": 0.5
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```